# Is the ReplicaSet name necessary in MongoClientURI Connection String?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am confused about the **use/need** of the MongoDB connection string [replicaSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option) option, when specifying a client URI for connection to a MongoDB replica set from a Java application.

I have 3 node instances of MongoDB running comprising the replica set, and each is specified as being a member of the same replica set.  I would like to connect to the replica set from my Java application.  I am confused from the documentation I have read, if it is even necessary to specify the replica set name in the connection string when I give a list of more than 2 hostnames.

Here is how I start my 3 node MongoDB instances.

1. Server1$: mongod --replSet "**rs0**"
2. Server2$: mongod --replSet "**rs0**"
3. Server3$: mongod --replSet "**rs0**"

I assume a negotiation then occurs, and a Primary is elected, and the remaining
are marked as Secondaries.

I would then want to connect to the replica set via the MongoClient call from my Java application. Is the actual replica set name even needed?  And do I need to list each member of the replica set, or does the MongoDB driver only need a single member of the replica set to determine the rest?

```java
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(
  new MongoClientURI(
    "mongodb://Server1,Server2,Server3/?replicaSet=rs0"
  )
);
```

**Do I need the replicaSet option?**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the replicaset, it connects in 'standalone' mode, and you lose replicaset features on the application end (no failing over). So if the server you connect to were to failover to another one, your application would not follow and reconnect to the new primary.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.replicaSet):

> When connecting to a replica set it is important to give a seed list
>   of at least two mongod instances. If you only provide the connection
>   point of a single mongod instance, and omit the replicaSet, the client
>   will create a standalone connection.

Comment: The current docs no longer say that, but even in the version you quoted, it says "If you only provide the connection point of a single mongod instance, AND...". This would lead one to believe that if you provided multiple connection points, the replicaSet parameter can be left out.

Comment: What if it is a sharded cluster? Each shard is a different replicaset.